# How to get Square Size Profile Image of Twitter and Facebook with Logo Embedded?

Tags: php, image, facebook, twitter, facebook-graph-api

Hi
while i go through this site
(http://www.talenthouse.com/creativeinvites/preview/ae2dd0ca9ac9d1881f27132df12b6dd1/219),
i came to see that while i login with help of either by twitter or facebook ,with my profile image, the F logo for Facebook and T Logo for twitter is embedded, how can i do that in PHP for facebook with help of Graph API??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of that page, you will see that the image is not actually embedded. They are just using css/html to overlay the "F"/"T" image:

```
<a>
  <span class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture);" />
  <img class="fb-decorator" src="http://assets.talenthouse.com/images_01/fb-member.jpg">
  <strong class="name">Mark</strong>
</a>
```

They may also have some special css applied to those elements - try inspecting it with Firebug or Chrome Dev tools - but you can see that its not embedded.